# What is the alternative of Crystal Report in asp.net core with vue.js applications?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-core, vuejs2, crystal-reports, report

I used crystal report(.rpt) files to generate pdf in my asp.net mvc4 application like this:

```
ReportDSRepo repo = new ReportDSRepo();
ReportClass objrpt = new ReportClass();
DataSet ReportResult;
ReportResult = repo.StockNew();
objrpt = new RptStockAll();//RptStockAll.rpt is a report file
objrpt.SetDataSource(dtStock);
objrpt.DataDefinition.FormulaFields["ReportName"].Text = "'StockInformation'";
objrpt.DataDefinition.FormulaFields["FSummery"].Text = "'Y'";
var rpt = gr.RenderReportAsPDF(objrpt);//definition of RenderReportAsPDF is given bellow
objrpt.Close();
return rpt;
```

And the generic class:

```
public class GenericReport<TReport> : Controller where TReport : ReportClass
    {
        public FileStreamResult RenderReportAsPDF(TReport rptDoc)
        {
            Stream stream = rptDoc.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
            return File(stream, "application/PDF");
        }
    }
```

I am developing a new dotnet core application (with vue Js2 as client). I came to know that I can't use crystal report in dotnet core applications. But I need to generate those reports anyhow. Is there any way to reuse the report files?
Or if there is any alternative of crystal report in asp.net core application then please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I know, it is an old question but we had a similar problem in our .net core app.

Instead of trying to port the reports to something .net core compatible, we served the reports from a .net framework 4.6+ based web service, and added the web service to the .net core project as a service reference.

It's not ideal but it worked out.